# Convert a string of integers from input to array of integers

Tags: r, shiny

I have a string of integers from an input text box (in Shiny) like this:

```
input[["var1"]]
"1,2,3,4"
```

I want to convert it into a numeric vector like:

```
values <- c(1,2,3,4)
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Use `strsplit` and `as.numeric`. Or `scan`.

Comment: Please add some code you have attempted first

Comment: Welcome to SO.  It is expected that you have attempted to solve the problem yourself before posting here, and to show that in your question.  Please edit your post to include what you've tried, including code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, yes I did  make an attempt earlier, and it is solved now. Please find the answer below.

> a <- "1,2,3,4"
>   a
>   [1] "1,2,3,4"
>   input_values <- as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(a,",")))
>   input_values
>   [1] 1 2 3 4

Thanks @Ananda,

Regards,
Ravijeet